# Close a window opened by a "jar" application started within my Java code

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have a (Swing + AWT) application which uses an external jar library (by calling a `main` method inside it).  This external application opens a window each time an event occurs (e.g. a button is pressed). Please consider that I have no access to the external jar source code.

How can I close the previously opened window before calling the main again?

The `actionPerformed` looks like this:

```
private void anActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
           String [] argv = {"arg1","arg2","arg3"};
           com.somepackage.SomeClass.main(argv);
        }
```

Comment: *"consider that I have no acces to the external jar source code."* It is still possible to extend and override in many cases.  Do you have access to the JavaDocs (or an IDE)?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Window.getOwnerLessWindows()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getOwnerlessWindows()).

Comment: I'll have a look at Window.getOwnerLessWindows. Unfortunately, I have no API documentation and it would be really hard to figure out by just looking at mathods' names :)

Comment: *"hard to figure out by just looking at mathods' names"* Easy to figure out by stepping through the code using the debugger of an IDE.

Comment: @andrew 
Yeah, that's why I'm a newbie :)
If I have some more time I'll definitely try to debug it and modify it with inheritance..the "getOwner" technique is enough for now 
Thank you anyway!

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Given *"the "getOwner" technique is enough for now"* you might enter that as an answer. It was a good comment, but would make a better answer.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry, no time to investigate and answer now. Feel free to post this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just guess - which might be wrong - that SomeClass.main calls a Ctor new SomeClass.

You could try to call it yourself:

```
SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass ();
```

It it is a JFrame, it is often initialized in main, and some properties are often set:

```
someclass.setSize (...
someclass.setLocation (...
someclass.setVisible (true);
```

If that works, you can store the someclass reference in a way, that you later can call

```
someclass.dispose ();
someclass = new SomeClass ();
```

Else you might search every class in the jar:

```
jar -tf some.jar
```

and use reflection and introspection to search for a ctor to call.

Or you try to extend SomeClass - maybe it isn't final and can be inherited.

```
class MyClass extends SomeClass
```

Comment: Very nice hint, but not a real answer...if no one will give something better (one is already on the comments!!) I'll pick this one

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the safest way, but you might consider using the [`Window#getWindows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows%28%29) method. If you know that a `Window` is created by calling the main method, you can ask for all `Window` instances right before calling the main and compare it to all `Window` instances afterwards. The new `Window` instance is the one you are looking for, and then you have a reference  allowing to dispose it afterwards.